# Cassandra cqlsh Copy Command Failed when invoked from remote server

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I want to invoke cqlsh COPY command on remote machine. I am trying below

```
ssh xx.xxx.xxx.xx sh {path_to_cassandra}/bin/cqlsh xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9042 -e "COPY {keyspace}.{table_name} TO '/tmp/file1.csv'"
```

I get the following error.

> Error : Improper Copy Command

Strange thing is when I am running the same command after going to remote server.It is working fine.

```
ssh xx.xxx.xxx.xx

sh {path_to_cassandra}/bin/cqlsh xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9042 -e "COPY ob_dev_otl.file_status TO '/tmp/file1.csv'"    //Working Fine
```

Please help me with some solution.Really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ssh xx.xxx.xxx.xx "{path_to_cassandra}/bin/cqlsh xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9042 -e \"COPY {keyspace}.{table_name} TO '/tmp/file1.csv'\""
```